# Launching app from HomeScreen (shortcut) and from App drawer, is not the same

Tags: android

I've encountered a weird behaviour. Maybe someone could clarify it.
When I download my app from GooglePlay, there are 2 icons that are added. One goes to the Home Screen as a shortcut and another goes to the App Drawer (the screen with all the different installed apps I got on my device).

Now here is the flow of events:

1. I install the app from GooglePlay
2. I launch the app once installation is complete, also from GooglePlay (There's an open button) --> This launches the app, shows a splash screen and goes to my main screen
3. I navigate around in my app to a different screen
4. I click the home button to go to the Home Screen.

Now the interesting part:

5. I press the Home Screen shortcut icon GooglePlay has created for me to get back to my app --> This takes me to the exact same screen I was in.
6. I click the home button again to go to the Home Screen.
7. This time, I press the App Drawer shortcut icon to get back to my app --> This shows the splash screen again and takes me to my main screen.

This happens constantly. Each shortcut launches to a different state (or screen). 
Notice that there is only one app in the Recent list.

On a the other hand. If I create the Home Screen shortcut myself, I get the same results when I launch the app from both icons.
Something is different with the shortcut GooglePlay is creating for me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** 
Here is the AndroidManifest.xml
Some names where changed. Some information (that is not related to intent-filters) had to be removed..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxxx.xxxxjh"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    tools:node="replace"
    android:name=".xxxxgggApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.StartupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.WelcomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/WelcomeActivityStyle"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.AccountActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.UrlSchemeHandlerActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="xxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="xxxx5.4" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.FileManagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:logo="@drawable/fm_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBar"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.ViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/launcher_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:parentActivityName=".view.activities.FileManagerActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".view.activities.FileManagerActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.DemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/launcher_activity_label"
        android:theme="@style/WelcomeActivityStyle"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.ApplicationSettingsActivity"
        android:logo="@drawable/fm_drawer"
        android:label="@string/AG_Settings"
        android:windojhoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.xxxx.xxxxjh.view.activities.FileManagerActivity" />

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:logo="@drawable/fm_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBar" />

    <service android:name="com.xxxx.sdk.controller.service.account.AccountService" >
       <!-- Actions and meta data goes here... -->
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.xxxx.sdk.controller.service.storage.StorageService">
       <!-- Actions and meta data goes here... -->
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.xxxx.sdk.controller.service.designFeed.DesignFeedService">
       <!-- Actions and meta data goes here... -->
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.xxxx.sdk.controller.service.ConfigService">
      <!-- Actions and meta data goes here... -->
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: This seems to be related to your intent-filters set in the manifest file. If you provide the file's content I will take a closer look.

Comment: Dr. Dreave  thank you for your time. I updated the question and provided the manifest. I had to rename some activities and remove some info but non of it was relevant to intent-filters. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you that this is not a bug in your project but an android default behaviour. I did some research ending up in the following threads. Maybe you can filter out some useful information and test these approaches in your project.

[App completely restarting when launched by icon press in launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126511/app-completely-restarting-when-launched-by-icon-press-in-launcher)

[Android application restarts when opened by clicking the application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449541/android-application-restarts-when-opened-by-clicking-the-application-icon)

Greetz.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you so much for your help.
Hopefully, this behaviour will be fixed by Google eventually.